# Loading multiple JS bundles in React Native iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native, code-splitting, metro-bundler

I'm trying to implement Code Splitting in a React Native app. Currently I managed to load multiple bundles in Android both in packager mode and in production mode.

However, on iOS I'm facing the following issue:
`Cannot initialize hmrClient twice`.
I'm trying to load the additional bundles using `[bridge.batchedBridge executeSourceCode]` which works in production mode but throws when using the packager.

When looking at the implementation of `executeSourceCode` I see that it indeed calls `setupHMRClientWithBundleURL` without checking if it was already initialized.

Is there any way to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems that `metro` does things a bit differently in `dev` vs `prod` and I didn't account for that.

Bundling JS with `--dev true` works. In order to avoid the `hmrClient` error it's better to use `[bridge.batchedBridge executeApplicationScript]` rather than `executeSourceCode`.